# How to show Uploaded video in youtube account should show in android application

Tags: android, video, youtube

I am developing and android application which in one module i want to show youtube videos in my list.
Here is my question how to create youtube account to upload videos and how to show uploaded videos in my app in list and play the videos.

Comment: go to this [developer console](https://developers.google.com/youtube/) to use youtube API

Comment: You can easily upload video on youtube after uploading a video youtube gives a unique id number of your video and this id will be used to show that video in Android application.